# Input() and threading

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create application which needs to get user input data while it prints things in a console at the same time.

```
import threading
import time

def F1():
    for i in range (100):
        print (i)
        time.sleep(1)
def input_data():
    txt = input('>')
    print(txt)

w1 = threading.Thread(target=F1)
w2 = threading.Thread(target=input_data)
w1.start()
w2.start()
```

But this way function `input()` stops all threads.
Is it possible to do it asynchronously in a python interpreter?
(I know that i could do it in tkinter easily.)

Comment: I think that you need to use *mutiprocessing*, not merely multithreading.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that `input()` would pause other threads - but if it didn't, the program would be essentially unusable, because your attempted input would constantly be overwritten by the other thread's output.

Comment: I tested the code example and confirmed that `input()` does not stop the other thread. However, the example obviously makes no sense since it is trying to use a single terminal for both input and output at the same time. A more sane example that simply updated a global variable (with locking) would show more clearly that `input` can be used in parallel with other threads.

Comment: The code in the question just works as expected for me. It prints numbers per second and keeps prompting until i send a newline. Also it only assigns what i typed to the `txt` variable. Windows 10, Python3.8.

Comment: Ok.... thx bro,,,, I tested it in IDLE what was a mistake.... thx for ur time and help

Comment: @YoungUser It is possible for IDLE to have different behaviour. You can post an answer for this question and accept it.